# Walsh-Hadamard Transform in r

Tags: r, image-processing

I search for a command to compute Walsh-Hadamard Transform of an image in R, but I don't find anything. In MATLAB `fwht` use for this. this command implement Walsh-Hadamard Tranform to each row of matrix. Can anyone introduce a similar way to compute Walsh-Hadamard on rows or columns of Matrix in R?

I find a package here:
http://www2.uaem.mx/r-mirror/web/packages/boolfun/boolfun.pdf

But why this package is not available when I want to install it?

Answer (score 0):

Packages that are not maintained get put in the Archive. They get put there when that aren't updated to match changing requirements or start making errors with changing R code base. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boolfun/index.html

It's possible that you might be able to extract useful code from the archive version, despite the relatively ancient version of R that package was written under.

The R code for walshTransform calls an object code routine:

```
walshTransform <- function ( truthTable ) # /!\ should check truthTable values are in {0,1}
{
    len <- log(length(truthTable),base=2)
    if( len != round(len) )
        stop("bad truth table length")
    res <- .Call( "walshTransform",
        as.integer(truthTable),
        as.integer(len))
    res
}
```

Installing the package succeeded on my Mac, but would require the appropriate toolchain on whatever OS you are working in.

Comment: It seems this R code use cpp file for Walsh_Hadamard Transform. I can't install archive version on windows